# How to make the 'optgrp' of the drop down select-able?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, select

Here is the plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/LqeGqg1HdOIkiMQrKn72?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="animalSelection" 
            ng-options="a.name group by a.subcat for a in animals">
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var animals = [
      {name: "great dane", subcat: "Dogs"},
      {name: "lab",        subcat: "Dogs"},
      {name: "tabby",      subcat: "Cats"},
      {name: "black",      subcat: "Cats"}
  ];
  // and put it in the $scope
  $scope.animals = animals;
});
```

I would like to select the subcat i.e Dogs Cats too as per the example

Comment: It's not possible with `select` element. Use customized select component.

Comment: not possible with native select.. may be you should look at some jquery angular control.

Comment: Thanks for confirming; however do you know something familiar custom control or link which would help me to attain the desired results

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?